# I have List<ApplicationMeta> i need to convert ApplicationMeta type

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-future

```
List<ApplicationMeta> apps = [];
@override
void initState() {
 UpiPay.getInstalledUpiApplications().then((value) {
  setState(() {
    this.apps = value;
    print('successfully append');
  });
}).catchError((e) {
  print('im in error part');
});
super.initState();
}
```

This program is about getupiapplications. getInstalledUpiApplications() function return 'List' but i have convert to ApplicationMeta. I got error.

Comment: you cannot convert List into a class. Please explain what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
apps.forEach((app) => {
//do whatever with app
print(app.name); //or whatever
})
```

In above code, `app` is of type `ApplicationMeta` forEach will let you iterate through each `app` in List `apps`. Your question is unclear, but it seems like you want to **iterate** through the `List`.